# Is it possible to select specific tables or views or any database objects to restore in a .bak file in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-backups, database-restore

I was thinking of this kind of update in the existing database.

For example: I have `Table1, Table2, Table3...TableN`. I changed `Table2` to `Table2SomethingUpdated` and `Table3` to `Table3SomethingUpdated` in my development environment. This is for too many tables, can I select only the updated tables from my development environment to the production database? Because other tables have existing data now.

Thanks.

Comment: Theres an existing Thread in dba Stackexchange -> [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/is-it-possible-to-backup-and-restore-part-of-a-database-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

A .bak file is a backup at the database level. You can't natively pick one specific object (table / view...).

However, you can find some workarounds. For example, you can restore your .bak  to create a new database, then you can pick what want from your restored database and send it to the original one... and finally remove your newly-created database.

Answer (score 0):

I create snapshots of any tables I may want to restore quickly without having to restore a backup by using the Select Into statement (Select * Into dbo.Table1_BU_20190812 From dbo.Table1).

I do this because at a majority of my customers locations it will take an act of Congress in order to get a backup restored and forget about creating another database thus is assuming that there is sufficient space to restore the database. Most of our customers choose to store files as BLOB objects so our database could be quite large.